# magento2 Display Shipping estimation Block in Product view page

Tags: magento2, shipping-address, estimate

In MAGENTO2 I want to show the "Estimate Shipping and Tax" in my product view page.

So I add the add the "`cart/shipping.phtml`" to the

```
catalog_product_view.xml
```

but it doesn't work.

Then I copy the arguments in

```
checkout.cart.shipping"(block)
```

it still useless, the Country,State/Province and below has nothing.

Here is my code that add to the `catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<referenceContainer name="alert.urls">
    <container name="cart.summary" label="Cart Summary Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="cart-summary" after="-">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="checkout.cart.summary.title" before="-" template="Magento_Theme::text.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="text" xsi:type="string">Summary</argument>
                <argument name="tag" xsi:type="string">strong</argument>
                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">summary title</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Shipping" name="checkout.cart.shipping" as="shipping" template="cart/shipping.phtml" after="checkout.cart.summary.title">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="types" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="form.input" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                <item name="deps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="0" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                </item>
                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/input</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="summary-block-config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="shipping-rates-validation" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <!--Step configuration components-->
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="block-summary" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                            <item name="deps" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="0" xsi:type="string">summary-block-config</item>
                            </item>
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="block-rates" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/cart/shipping-rates</item>
                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                                </item>
                                <item name="block-shipping" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/cart/shipping-estimation</item>
                                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                                    <item name="deps" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">block-summary.block-shipping.address-fieldsets</item>
                                    </item>
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="address-fieldsets" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="deps" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="0" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">address-fieldsets</item>
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="city" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">115</item>
                                                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.city</item>
                                                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                </item>
                                                <item name="country_id" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">110</item>
                                                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.country_id</item>
                                                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                </item>
                                                <item name="region_id" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/region</item>
                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">112</item>
                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                                        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/select</item>
                                                        <item name="customEntry" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.region</item>
                                                    </item>
                                                    <!-- Value of region_id field is filtered by the value of county_id attribute -->
                                                    <item name="filterBy" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[${ $.provider }:${ $.parentScope }.country_id]]></item>
                                                        <item name="field" xsi:type="string">country_id</item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                                <!-- The following items override configuration of corresponding address attributes -->
                                                <item name="region" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <!-- Make region attribute invisible on frontend. Corresponding input element is created by region_id field -->
                                                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">111</item>
                                                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.region</item>
                                                </item>
                                                <item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <!-- post-code field has custom UI component -->
                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
                                                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.postcode</item>
                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">114</item>
                                                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="checkoutProvider" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <container name="checkout.cart.totals.container" as="totals" label="Shopping Cart Totals">
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Totals" name="checkout.cart.totals" template="cart/totals.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="block-totals" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/cart/totals</item>
                                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">totals</item>
                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/cart/totals</item>
                                </item>
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <!-- sort order for this totals is configured on admin panel-->
                                    <!-- Stores->Configuration->SALES->Sales->General->Checkout Totals Sort Order -->
                                    <!-- <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                                             <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/subtotal</item>
                                             <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                 <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Subtotal</item>
                                                 <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/cart/totals/subtotal</item>
                                             </item>
                                         </item> -->
                                    <item name="shipping" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/cart/totals/shipping</item>
                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Shipping</item>
                                            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/cart/totals/shipping</item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                    <!-- <item name="grand-total" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/grand-total</item>
                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order Total</item>
                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/cart/totals/grand-total</item>
                                            </item>
                                    </item> -->
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </container>
        <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart" name="checkout.cart.methods.bottom" template="cart/methods.phtml">
            <container name="checkout.cart.methods" as="methods" label="Payment Methods After Checkout Button">
                <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Link" name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage.bottom" template="onepage/link.phtml" />
                <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\QuoteShortcutButtons" name="checkout.cart.shortcut.buttons" />
            </container>
        </block>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Did you ever get this working?